# Does solace jms implement JMS 2.0 spec?

Tags: jms, solace

I am trying to use the asyn send feature availabe in Solace, but I intend to use JMS for abstraction and not use it directly using JCSMP.

JMS 2.0 supports asyn send among other new features: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html

Does solace jms support JMS 2.0? If not, is there a plan to support it in near future?

Answer (score 3):

The Solace JMS API does not currently support JMS 2.0. There are future plans to implement support for JMS 2.0 but a release date has not yet been determined.

Answer (score 0):

It's now supported on AMQP Protocol :

https://tutorials.solace.dev/java-amqp-qpid-jms2

Answer (score 0):

Today's release add support to JMS 2.0 API, only JMS 1.1 features are supported as of now.
JMS 2.0 features may be added later.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.solacesystems/sol-jms

Spring Boot 3 is now supported as well
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.solace.spring.boot

[image: 19th of may 2023 release notes]